# Resizing TYPE_CUSTOM BufferedImages?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

When I read a JPEG from disk, Java sometimes gives me a BufferedImage whose getType() returns TYPE_CUSTOM -- that is, it has a custom color model. I'd like to resize this BufferedImage but I'm not sure how to construct the destination object. Can someone please provide sample code for using the following constructor?

[BufferedImage(ColorModel cm, WritableRaster raster, boolean isRasterPremultiplied, Hashtable properties)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#BufferedImage(java.awt.image.ColorModel,%20java.awt.image.WritableRaster,%20boolean,%20java.util.Hashtable))

I would like to create a BufferedImage of the same type as the source, just bigger, and transfer the contents over. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question, it looks like [ImageTypeSpecifier](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageTypeSpecifier.html) is the answer. Specifically:

1. Invoke [ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(RenderedImage image)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageTypeSpecifier.html#createFromRenderedImage(java.awt.image.RenderedImage)) to get back an `ImageTypeSpecifier` from the image with the custom color model.
2. Invoke [ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(int width, int height)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageTypeSpecifier.html#createBufferedImage(int,%20int)) on the `ImageTypeSpecifier` from step 1 to create a new image with the same color model as the original image.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @dacwe I've updated the answer with clarified steps. I haven't touched this code in over 9 years so I don't have a running example to share with you.